# How to create a new file in libgdx?

Tags: java, file, libgdx, save

I am trying to create a new file into my game ( for saving purporses ) using Libgdx. I have no idea how to do this and all tutorials seem to write / read but not create the files.

```
 try {
    //File file = new File("LnRSave.txt");
    FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("LnRSave.txt");
    // if file doesnt exists, then create it
    if (!file.exists()) {

        file.createNewFile();
    }

    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file.getAbsoluteFile());
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    bw.write(jPoika.toJson(inventory));
    bw.close();

    System.out.println("Done");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do it like this:

```
FileHandle file = Gdx.files.local("myfile.txt");
file.writeString("My god, it's full of stars", false);
```

Check out the documentation [here](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/File-handling#writing-to-a-file)

Answer (score 3):

I recommend you to use `Preferences` class provided by libgdx. Use `Preferences prefs = Gdx.app.getPreferences("YourAppName")` to get your preferences, you can use `prefs.contains("inventory")` to check if the key is there. Add or change a value with `prefs.putInteger("inventory", value)` (you can also putString, putFloat etc.) and use `prefs.flush()` after that.